# .net webapp deployed on azure with a not working default index page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, .net-6.0

Deployed a demo .net 6 web app to azure web app service through github action (with secret created from publish profile).

The default index page is not working. Did I miss anything?
[image]

However, if I manually add "/index". It works.
[image]

Comment: If you are using windows or linux? For windows you can inspect the log files from the browser at https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker.
This could happen when your app was failing to start up due to an unhandled exception thrown in my startup code.
Also make sure your default page is listed in yourweb> Settings> configuration> default documents and is above hostingstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to deploy Azure Web App using GIT HUB Actions

- In Visual Studio, create .NET CORE 6 App, build and run locally.
- Push the created web app from local to GitHub Repository.
- In VS, Navigate to `Git` Menu and click on `Create Git Repository`.
  [image]
- Create a new repository and push the local code to `Git`.
- In Azure App Service, create an Azure App service with `.net core 6` runtime stack.
- In Azure App service => `Deployment Center`  => Under `Settings` tab, select `Source` as `GitHub`  and select the required fields.
- Select the newly created repository and save.
  [image]

Make sure all the files are deployed under `wwwroot` directory.

Thanks to @SnehaAgrawal-MSFT for the Comment.

- In Azure App Service => `Configuration` => `Default documents`, add your default file `html/cshtml` file.

[image]

- When we deploy Azure App, by default `web.config` will be created. Even we can set `defaultdocument` in `web.config`  under `system.webServer` section.

```cs
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="YouPage.html" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

- Now you will be able to access the app with your default page.